# Swift: How to Parse JSON Facebook graph data for group members

Tags: json, swift

How can I parse this JSON into an array of dictionaries - [String: AnyObject]?

```
typealias FBUser = [String: AnyObject]
var fbGroup = [FBUser]()

func logUserGroup() {
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "88##########6270/members", parameters: ["fields": "id, name"], HTTPMethod: "GET")
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let resultdict = result as? [NSDictionary] {

                for member in resultdict {
                    var user = FBUser()
                    if let idvalue = member["id"] as? String {
                        user["id"] = idvalue
                    }
                    if let name = member["name"] as? String {
                        user["name"] = name
                    }
                    self.fbGroup.append(user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Facebook JSON:

```
{
  data =  (
            {
        id = 102055#####10000;
        name = "Kristian";
    },
            {
        id = 10208######08475;
        name = "Oren";
    },
            {
        id = 1020#######57409;
        name = "Ron";
    }
  };
}
```

If there is a good resource for different parsing techniques that would be very helpful.

Comment: JSONModel is a good data modelling third party library. You can find it and it's usages at https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/.

Comment: Were you able to parse it?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the recommendation.